# how and where to add an 'Esc' listener to a litElement component?

Tags: javascript, html, lit-element

I have modal component rendered using litElement and I'd like to make it closeable via the Escape key, for any and all instances of this modal component.

My question is where and how do I do that? In the render, in firstUpdated? Your help would be appreciated.

Relevant excerpt:

```
    close() {
        this.hidden = true;
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('modal-closed'));
    }

    _addKeyListener() {
        this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
            if (event.key === 'Escape') {
                this.close(); //presumably
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.hidden) {
            return html``;
        }

        return html`
            <div id="background" class="${classMap({'u-is-hidden': this.hidden})}">
                <div class="modal">
                    <div id="modal-close" class="${classMap({'u-is-hidden': !this.closeable})}">
                        <img src="img/close-icon.svg" @click="${this.close.bind(this)}" alt="close">
                    </div>
                    <div id="modal-header">
                        <slot name="header"></slot>
                    </div>
                    <div id="modal-body">
                        <slot name="body"></slot>
                    </div>
                    <div id="modal-footer">
                        <slot name="footer"></slot>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
    }
```

Comment: Check the documentation here: https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/events

Answer (score 1):

I use *updated* lifecycle function for the same purposes in my modal component:

```
import { html, LitElement } from "lit";
import { customElement, property, query } from "lit/decorators";
import { classMap } from "lit/directives/class-map";
import { elementStyles } from "./modal.element.styles";

@customElement('very-custom-modal')
export class ModalElement extends LitElement {
  
  static styles = [elementStyles];
  
  @property({ type: Boolean })
  open = false;

  private _handlerClose() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("close"));
  }

  private _keydownHandler(e: Event) {
    if ((e as KeyboardEvent).code === 'Escape') {
      this._handlerClose();
    }
  }

  updated() {
    if (this.open) {
      this.getRootNode().addEventListener('keydown', (e: Event) => this._keydownHandler(e));
    } else {
      this.getRootNode().removeEventListener('keydown', (e: Event) => this._keydownHandler(e));
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    const classes = { 'modal': true, 'open': this.open, 'hidden': !this.open };
    return html`
      <div  class=${classMap(classes)}>
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close" @click=${this._handlerClose}>&times;</span>
          <p class="text">Some text in the Modal..</p>
        </div>
      </div>  
    `;
  }
}
```

And styles:

```
import { css } from "lit";

export const elementStyles = css`
  .modal {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  .modal-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc((100vh - 300px) / 2);
    left: calc((100vw - 500px) / 2);
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 50%;
    top: 30%;
  }
  .close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .open {
    display: block;
  }
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

This component changes it behavior on dependency of state the property ‘open’. By default it is false, so the component has the ‘.hidden’ class. After changing ‘open’ property the component updates in according with Lit documentation (https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/#reactive-update-cycle) and updates with ‘.open’ class in case if the property is 'true'. I use ‘updated’ event for adding/removing keydown listener. As a little conclusion, the component hooks the keydown events only if it active (displayed), otherwise we don't need this handler, so could remove it in case if the control property is 'false'. Since the property should be set outside the component we need emit 'close' event to the parent component for changing property to 'false'.

Comment: I think this is a good answer generally - I gave you an upvote. But, if you are interested in improving this further, add some comments to your code, and write a little bit more about how/why it works for you versus just 'It works for me.'

Comment: I added some comments to code, but nothing much, code is very simply.